Electric Potential in circuit confusion
I reviewed some of the fundamental physics and I looked back at the equation for Electric potential at a point p: $$V(p) = k \sum_{i} {\frac {q_i} {r_i}}$$ where

p is the point at which the potential is evaluated;

ri is the distance between point p and point i at which there is a nonzero charge;

qi is the charge at point i


and I still find it's kind of contradicting with the simple circuit model such as the one below. Both point a and point b should be neutral with no net charge so their electric field is 0 and the voltage is flat on the graph according to Gauss law. I understand the electric potential of point b is ε higher than that of point a (i.e. V(b)-V(a)=ε) means it takes ε work to move a +1 test charge from point a to point b along the circuit.
But according to Electric potential formula at a point, should that also imply there are higher positive net charge concentration around point b than point a so how can they both neutral with no net charge? Does that mean the equation for Electric potential at a point does not apply in a circuit model but if so, why?

image reference: https://tikz.net/electric_circuit_voltage_plots/

I am not sure if I am on the right track. What I think is since the definition of Electric potential is the amount of work needed per unit of electric charge to move the charge from one point to another point in an electric field. Electric field is a conservative field, the potential difference between 2 points is independent of the path taken. If there is a path in the circuit going from point A to point B and it takes ε of work, even it is very difficult or impossible to compute Electric potential for point A and point B with the equation above, but we can still conclude the result of V(B)-V(A)=ε without calculating it.

This is an open circuit so that no current would flow that would produce the voltage drop over the resistor you are indicating.

Point a at both ends of the circuit are the same point so the circuit is connected. It is showing this way just to in line with the x-axis of the graph.

@freecharly I agree with the OP. The two end nodes $a$ have the same identifier, i.e. they are the same node.

@Bob D That's right, I overlooked it.

The equation applies when the potential is assigned a value of zero at infinity, which makes sense when you are looking the potential due to the contribution of many point charges.
But the assignment of zero potential is purely arbitrary when it comes to a circuit. In  your circuit a potential of zero has been assigned to the negative terminal of the battery. Then the potential at every other point in the circuit is with respect to that point of zero potential.
Hope this helps.

Thanks for your answer. But it shouldn't make a difference when we are computing the potential difference. Let V(∞->A) and V(∞->B) be the work required to move a +1 charge from point ∞ away to point A and to point B respectively using the Electric potential equation above. If we set point A as arbitrary ground of the circuit then the work required to move a +1 charge from point A to point B will be V(∞->B)-V(∞->A)=V(B)-V(A)=V(B)=ε. But what I am having trouble understanding is that it looks to me that V(∞->A)=V(∞->B) since point A and B are both surrounded by 0 net charges

@Matt if I understand what you’re saying, it takes more work to move a unit positive charge from infinity to the positive terminal of the battery than to move it to the negative terminal,  with the difference in work equaling the battery emf

Yes, because it takes emf of work to bring a unit positive charge from point A to point B and given electric field is a conservative field. Please let me know what you think

@Matt sounds reasonable to me. Do you have a problem with that?

No it does not mean that the equation for Electric potential at a point does not apply in a circuit model.
What is happening is that the charge is not correctly computed in a circuit model. The Kirchhoff laws require that currents into one circuit node sum to zero, so there can never be any charge delivered to the node, it remains uncharged. The equation for electric potential then (correctly) will tell you that with no charge you get zero potential, so that equation is not to blame...
You can of course fix the situation by giving each node a (parasitic) capacitance, which will in the circuit model be represented as a small capacitor to ground (or to infinity, if you want to treat the ground node as just another node like all others). In that way you can have a net charge flowing from the real components in and out of this parasitic capacitor and that represents the charge on the node, which can then explain the nonzero field around that node.

If there was no current flowing in the circuit the positive terminal of the cell would have a positive charge and the negative terminal of the cell would have a negative charge produced by the electrochemical reaction within the cell but overall the system would be neutral.
When the circuit is completed and a current flows that difference in the concentration of charges at the two terminals is maintained by the electrochemical reaction within the cell.
